How to check what constructor overload is used
If I have a class constructor with two overloads taking in different inputs, is there a way to tell them apart? For example,
class example
{
    double ExampleDouble;
    char ExampleChar;
    public:
    example(double ED)
    {
        ExampleDouble=ED;
    }
    example(char EC)
    {
        ExampleChar=EC;
    }
};
int main()
{
    example var('a');
    return 0;
}

Is there any way to tell whether "var" is storing a double or char?
I tried using var.ExampleChar but it threw an error, and there were no online resources regarding this issue.

but it threw an error what error? If you show us the error we can point you to online resources, or explain it right here in an answer.

var.ExampleChar in main would be an error because the member is private.

Try godbolt.com, you can share the link of your code and error message. I guess ExampleChar is private so you cannot access it. Otherwise even if it's uninitialized you can access the members, although might be an undefined behavior.

The simple way would be to do something like this
class example
{
public:
    double ExampleDouble;
    char ExampleChar;
    bool IsChar;
    example(double ED)
    {
        ExampleDouble=ED;
        IsChar=false;
    }
    example(char EC)
    {
        ExampleChar=EC;
        IsChar=true;
    }
};

But you are reinventing the wheel. The class you have here is similar to what std::variant already does for you.
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::variant<double, char> var('a');
    if (holds_alternative<char>(var))
        std::cout << "its a char\n";
    return 0;
}


Thanks a lot, I didn't even know about them

std::variant was introduced with C++17. You might need to make sure that your compiler supports this version of C++.
